# Use a different region notation than the system's region notation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

On iOS, an app can use a different language than the system language if the developer passes the `NSLocale` to the right instances, or else if the proper values are written to `NSUserDefault`'s `AppleLanguages` key.

I don't seem to find a way to do this also for the region, the part that takes care of number formatting.

The use case here is that I want a `UITextfield`'s `DecimalPad` keyboard to show a comma for a decimal no matter what the system's region is set to.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AppleLocale` instead of `AppleLanguages`.

E.g. `-AppleLocale nl_BE` will set the locale to Dutch with region Belgium.